# Why do I have access to private field of the class not only inside the class itself?

Tags: c#

Why can I change the state of `CancellationTokenSource` private field in `Main(string[]?)` method? It supposed to be accessable inside the class!

```cs
using System.Threading;

namespace MyGame
{
    public class Game : Application
    {
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

        public void Run()
        {
            RunAsync(_cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        internal static void Main(string[]? args)
        {
            var game = new Game();

            game._cts.Cancel();
            game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Main` is inside the class. The method being static doesn't change anything other than the fact that you need an instance to access the private field rather than being able to just access `_cts` (which is just short for `this._cts` by the way, so really non-static methods do this too).

Comment: This is weird that I can access non-static private field inside static method. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Access modifiers apply to the entire class. Given that the method is in the class, it would be weird to break this rule solely because it's static.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, CancellationTokenSource is the type/class of _cts, so you would be able to access CancellationTokenSource static methods.

However if you refer to _cts, the thing is Main is inside Game, as Jesse mentions. If you don't want it to be able to access it you can declare Main outside Game class but still in the same namespace.

```
using System.Threading;

namespace MyGame
{
    public class Game : Application
    {
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;

        public void Run()
        {
            RunAsync(_cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[]? args)
        {
            var game = new Game();
            game.Run();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Methods can't be declared outside of a class. You would need to make a new class to put it in. However, it would probably be easier to move `_cts` and `Run()` to a new class rather than moving the main method.

Comment: My bad, edited the snippet to quick

Comment: It's fine. It's just weird to see that I can access private fields inside static methods. Anyway, thanks for response.